# How would you plot this 3D visualization in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I want to take an image and represent the dimensions of the image as spatial coordinates and the pixel values as the 3rd dimension represented by height. Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQoDO.png) of what I would like to do.

How would you do this with matplotlib or plotly?

Comment: Can you give an example of code you've tried so far?

Comment: Use [`ax.plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface) and in general please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the image is in HWC format, is gray-scale (i.e. C=1) and is a numpy array, something along the lines of:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.uniform(size=(10,10,1))

X = np.arange(0, img.shape[1])
Y = np.arange(0, img.shape[0])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = img.squeeze()

# Plot the surface.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

Inspired by: [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html).
Hope this helps!